# converting all the numbers in a javascript array to 2 decimal places within a function

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function to make all the numbers in an array to 2 decimal places

```
function convert(radi){
    var i = 0;
    while(radi !== null) {
        radi += radi[i].toFixed(2);
    }
    return  radi;
}
convert(radi);
console.log(radi);
convert(areas);
console.log(areas);



    *
```

Comment: Hey Diane! It would help to know what kind of data would be sent into your `convert` function. Are they floats that need to be rounded to 2 decimal places? Are they integers that you want to turn into decimals (e.g., 2 => .02)? What kind of data is coming through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a starting array:

```
arr = [0.445 , 1.54645 , 5.432];
```

Use the following function which uses a `for` loop and `push` on to a empty array instead of a `while` loop and `+=` (addition assignment). `+=` might not be doing what you think it does. For insight into addition assignment functionality see [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

```
function convert(arr){
    newArr =[];
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        newArr.push(arr[i].toFixed(2));
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Usage:

```
arr = convert(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function to iterate through array and use toFixed to set accuracy, toFixed return string, so you need to wrap toFixed function with Number.

```
radi.map( item => Number(item.toFixed(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
radi.map(e=>e.toFixed(2))
```

redi is any array of numbers

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using the `map` method described in the previous answer.  If you're looking to modify the function you've come up with, here's a close solution that will work.

```js
function convert(radi){
    var i = 0;
    while(radi[i]) {
        radi[i] = radi[i].toFixed(2);
        i++;
    }
    return  radi;
}

var radi = [1, 3.3454, 87.2];
radi = convert(radi);
console.log(radi);
```